# Encode only non-ASCII characters to HTML entities, keeping HTML tags

Tags: html, ruby, character-encoding, html-entities

I'm pulling text from a database, processing it, and uploading it as plain text to an HTML email creator. The email tool is internal to my company. It can take simple HTML tags, but it can't handle non-ASCII characters. They will be displayed as `¿` to the end user. As an example of what I'm working with, the source text from the database might look like this:

```
The café was…<br/>“delicious”.
```

My desired output would be

```
The caf&eacute; was&hellip;<br/>&ldquo;delicious&rdquo;.
```

If I use an HTML entity encoder like [HTMLEntities](http://htmlentities.rubyforge.org/) it encodes everything, including the tag brackets (`<` and `>`). Here's the output from using HTMLEntities:

```
The caf&eacute; was&hellip;&lt;br/&gt;&ldquo;delicious&rdquo;.
```

If I upload the above to the HTML email tool, the end-user would see this in their email:

```
The café was…<br/>“delicious”
```

Is there any way to get the best of both worlds, where the tags are left alone but the non-ASCII characters are encoded as HTML entities? I could continue using HTMLEntities and just use a `gsub`; something like this:

```
coder = HTMLEntities.new
string = "The café was…<br/>“delicious”."
coder.encode(string, :named).gsub(/&lt;/, "<").gsub(/&gt;/, ">")
#=> "The caf&eacute; was&hellip;<br/>&ldquo;delicious&rdquo;."
```

This seems pretty fragile to me. Any better way to do it?

Comment: What HTML email generator are you talking about? How are you sending this email?

Comment: It's an email tool that's internal to my company. It takes simple html, but apparently it can't take unencoded special characters.

Comment: I'm assuming that means it's not under your control then? It would seem that it's not handling unicode properly, which is rather unfortunate for today. There are HTML encoding tools out there that can take whitelists of characters to allow through, but I can't remember the names of them (or if they were even in Ruby). They are out there, though.

Comment: Btw, "these types of characters" are just any non-ASCII character. Unicode is the character encoding that is preferred as nearly every character can be represented in it, unlike ASCII which is very limited.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to check encoding of your data!
Make sure your database are saving your data in UTF-8, and add:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
```

in top of your Ruby file.

Comment: Yes, I've checked that. It's not Ruby that's having the trouble encoding. It's the email program I'm uploading the text to. It's requiring special characters to properly encoded before they'll be displayed to the end-user.

Comment: @BrunnoDosSantos That's what he says he's using in the question…